# Strong induction inequality $\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3}\leq\frac{5}{8}-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality, induction

Use strong induction to prove that

$$\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3}\leq\frac{5}{8}-\frac{1}{n}$$    $$n\geq2$$

I'm not sure how to go about this. I used base cases n=2, and n=3 but I'm having trouble with the actual induction part.

I said this as my Induction Hypothesis: 
Suppose the claim is true for n=2, 3, ... ,k. We must show it holds for n=k+1.

Not sure where to go from there :T.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Not that it is helpful for this question but the infinite sum $\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots$ is $1$ less than [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) so less than $0.20205690316$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it holds for $n-1$ it suffices to show that
$$\frac1{n^3}\le\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n=\frac1{n(n-1)}$$
which is obviously true.

You should see that adding
\begin{align*}\frac1{2^3}+\ldots\frac1{(n-1)^3}&\le\frac58-\frac1{n-1}\\
\frac1{n^3}&\le\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\end{align*}
yields
$$\frac1{2^3}+\ldots\frac1{n^3}\le\frac58-\frac1n\!\!\!$$

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? Sorry, but this is a bit confusing to me. How you get to the conclusion, to be specific.

Comment: @ChrisJang What conclusion?

Comment: The part after "yields" . I get lost after that. Do you use substitution, or...?

Comment: @ChrisJang That's easy. Just compute the sum both inequalities above. (left sides and right sides separately)

Comment: OOOOHHH Okay, I understand now; you add the two inequalities. Thank you very much! :)